# Cholesky Decomposition and Equal Diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

If we know that a matrix $A$ has a unique Cholesky decomposition $L$, i.e.           $A = LL^{T}$, and all the diagonal elements of $L$ are equal, can we say anything about the original matrix? I’m interested in finding an equivalent but simpler property.